# Conjugate symmetry of real-coefficient filters in Oppenheime's Discrete Time Signal Processing

Tags: filters

Is someone able to tell me where and how I could look up the yellow part in Oppenheime's Discrete Time Signal Processing, or explain it?

[image: ECE-700 Filterbank Notes, Phil Schniter, March 10, 2008]

Comment: The DTFT is periodic with period $2\pi$.  $$ e^{j(\omega + 2\pi)} = e^{j\omega} \qquad \forall \omega \in \mathbb{R} $$  and also keep in mind that $$ e^{j\pi} = -1$$  the conjugate symmetry is that **if** $h[n]$ is real (that is $\Im\{h[n]\} =  0 \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{Z} \quad $), then $$ H(e^{-j\omega}) = \overline{H(e^{j\omega})}$$  and complex conjugates have the same magnitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fourier transform of a **real** function $x[n]$ is conjugate symmetric. That is,
$$X^*(\omega)=X(-\omega)$$
This is easy to observe. From the definition of FT: $$X(\omega)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}x[n]e^{-j\omega n}$$
Conjugating both sides:

$$\begin{align}
X^*(\omega)=&\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}x^*[n]\left(e^{-j\omega n}\right)^*\\
&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}x[n]e^{j\omega n}\\
&=X(-\omega)
\end{align}$$

A direct consequence of this property (that you can easily verify) is that

> 1- The real part and the magnitude of the Fourier transform of a real valued function are **even** functions of $\omega$. That is, $\Re\{X(\omega)\}=\Re\{X(-\omega)\}$ and $|X(\omega)|=|X(-\omega)|$.
>
> 2- The imaginary part and the phase of the Fourier transform of a real valued function are odd functions of $\omega$. That is, $\Im\{X(\omega)\}=-\Im\{X(-\omega)\}$ and $\angle X(\omega)=-\angle X(-\omega)$.

Based on the above explanation, for a real-coefficient filter $h$, the magnitude of the frequency response is an even function.

$$\begin{align}
|H(e^{j(\omega-\pi)})|&=|H(e^{j(-\omega-\pi)})|\\
&=|H(e^{j(-\omega-\pi+2\pi)})|=|H(e^{j(\pi-\omega)})|
\end{align}$$
and the second line is because DTFT is $2\pi$-periodic. Hence we can add $2\pi$ and the result does not change.

Comment: It is interesting to note in addition that H is symmetric about Pi for H(2 alpha - omega) = H(omega).

Comment: Yes. The two properties in the answer are valid for both discrete and continuous Fourier transforms. In addition, DTFT is periodic (with period $2\pi$).

Comment: It was less about distinction between discrete and continuous, but more about a sufficient symmetry-condition.

Comment: I see. Just added the note for more usability for the future audience..